# Huge CPU Load on ARM based board for While loop

Tags: c, linux, arm, cross-compiling

I have an iMX6 board and one of my application was taking much CPU without doing much work.. I wrote a sample code instead of just posting the original application

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("Hello World\r\n");
        while(1);
        return 0;
}
```

This is taking 25% of the CPU Load.. Can you please tell me what I can do to reduce the CPU Load

Update:

Adding a sleep of 50 microsecond reduced the CPU Load to directly 2%

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("Hello World\r\n");
        while(1)
        {
                usleep(50);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the loop. Halt the processor. Add a sleep.

Comment: You're telling the computer to work as fast as it can (because of the `while` loop without a sleep or any other time consuming operation). This is to be expected.  It's a feature! As above are the basic solutions. Good luck.

Comment: How do you get this cpu load value ?

Comment: using the top command in linux..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of [busy looping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).

The `while` loop is consuming all the available resources of one of your cores. Since you have four cores, you're seeing 25% CPU load.

You can cause a timed-delay that won't use any CPU resources as follows:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

int main()
{
  pollingDelay = 100
  //do stuff

  //sleep:
  #ifdef _WIN32
  Sleep(pollingDelay);
  #else
  usleep(pollingDelay*1000);  /* sleep for 100 milliSeconds */
  #endif

  //do stuff again
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to wait for the user, the following works. Yyou may need to do something more complicated if the user defiantly presses keys before enter.

```
printf("Press ENTER key to Continue\n");  
getchar();
```

Comment: @md.jamal: The busy loop induced by `while` utilizes 100% of the core it runs on. Since you say your program is using only 25% of the CPU, you must have four other cores (100%/4=25%).